# Infinitive/ Gerund/ By+gerund

Tags: grammar

I've been searching Google but the corpus does not really help this time. Are all the examples below correct and idiomatic? I will appreciate it if you support your answers with rules and not just native speaker intuitions:

> The best way to aquire knowledge is **reading**.
>
> The best way to acquire knowledge is **to read**.
>
> The best way to acquire knowledge is **by reading**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They all seem fine to me and have the same meaning, though the first example where "by" has been omitted is *perhaps* less common than your third example where it is included.

Structurally, your first two examples have the participle and infinitive clauses as predicative complements in a reversible specifying type of construction (cf. *Reading*  / *To read is the best way to acquire knowledge*) .

Your third example is slightly different by virtue of the predicative element being complement of the preposition "by" instead of being related directly to the verb as in the others. But it's still a predicative (more precisely a predicative oblique) in that it relates to a predicand (i.e. the subject NP *The best way ....*)